# Merging separate polygons to one polygon without using (buffer, dissolve, and neg buffer)?

Tags: qgis, polygon, arcgis-10.4

I want to merge separate polygons to one polygon. But I want to do it without using (buffer, dissolve tool ets). I want to visualize the sepated polygons in to one polygon.

I can work in ArcGIS and Qgis.

[image: so the blue polygons has to be one]

Comment: Its about the blue polygons :)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: I think that this is very nitpicking... OP is not asking how to do it in both, just that he can use both tools.

Comment: I kind of agree with @RoVo, but I would like to know why using buffer, dissolve, etc. (so not any kind of tool?) should be used.

Comment: Asking how to do something without the tools that permit it makes no sense in either package, and doubly so for both. Please choose a software environment and explain why what you have tried is not acceptable to your need.